# Is it considered a good practice using shorter property names in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

According to multiple sources like [this presentation by Johan Euphrosine](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1o7z8gWBTeL3SLJ-iClaUjLTYF6zAQn4v47nr5IaTBbM), AppEngine stores property names together with data and indexes. Because of this I use shortened versions of kind and property names in the Datastore to save space in disk:

```
@Entity("p")
public class PersistentClass {

    @Property("n")
    private String name;

}
```

The index entries for this entity would be in the line of:

```
PersistentClass:1
PersistentClass:name:foo:PersistentClass:1
```

As compared with (applying shortened property names):

```
p:1
p:n:foo:p:1
```

That's 73% compression, but this is a theoretical exercise and is hard to push forward without internal knowledge of the platform. My question is: is this common practice? Has anyone measured the savings of stored shortened property names in NoSQL, and AppEngine in particular?

Comment: From what I recall you can have a "name" you use in your application and a name you use interally in the datastore (in python anyway). Simply put, if you store millions of records then your saving will be "num records X string length" for each and every one. So if you anticipate having lots and lots of records....

Comment: I think the implications of long property names in the datastore are similar to the issue with JSON - having short attributes names will help you both when storing your entity in the DS and when sending it to your client apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to answer this question is probably with a simple test. I just threw a sample application into a Gist (https://gist.github.com/jeremydw/7201456) where I tested the creation of 2000 entities of a model with a long property name, and 2000 entities of a model with a single-character property name.

Using the datastore stats module (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats) confirms that the longer property name does take up more disk space. (278KB in this particular experiment.) What would also be an interesting test would be to measure time to create or retrieve the entities, since that will also impact the speed of your application.

Here are the results of a single test:

```
name: l_PersistentClass2, bytes: 1507635
name: super_very_long_property_name_PersistentClass1, bytes: 1787607
difference: 279972 bytes
```

Comment: That's awesome. If I'm reading this test correctly, it only sums storage used by the data, but not by indexes.

Comment: Yep, looking at my devappserver's datastore stats (using the datastore viewer), the index sizes (in bytes) for both the Kind with the long property name and the short property name are identical. So, index sizes are the same, storage is different, and RPC time is (potentially, probably) different as well. Now, we can draw some interesting conclusions from this, but the best thing to do would probably be to profile your real application to see if the difference matters with respect to price and speed. :)

Comment: The difference per entity is 140 bytes which is IMO negligible. It should not even be visible on RPC. This all sounds like a premature optimisation.

Comment: As commented by Dragonx below, it depends on the application. Twitter-style apps with many small fields and a huge number of entities may benefit from this, others not so much.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with it - this should be a totally acceptable practice.

Whether it actually saves you any money is another matter. That's is of course totally app dependent, but our biggest expenses are DB operations and bandwidth. After two years operation (constantly saving data) our total data storage expense is only 5% of total expense.

You should really do a bit of calc to see if this will actually have any meaningful impact on your total GAE cost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is generally a good idea.

This would probably be of negligible impact for the indexes, I don't think the indexes actually use the property names for every index entry.

However, the property names are used in every entity stored.  I don't have numbers with me right now, but I did run a test with an entity that had about 80 integer properties.  In this case, the long property names were a significant overhead above the actual integer values, and using 1 or 2 character property names reduced the sizes of the entities significantly.

However, I only had a few thousand of those entities stored, so the actual effect on cost was minimal.  But now every time I bring up those entities in the datastore view, I have to bring up my source code to figure out which property is which.